Explicit construction of pushout in $\mathsf{Grp}$ when one of the maps is surjective
$\require{AMScd}$
Consider the following commutative diagram in $\mathsf{Grp}$:
$$
\begin{CD}
A @>a>> B\\
@V b V V @VV c V\\
C @>>d> D
\end{CD}
$$
Assume that this is a pushout square. Furthermore, assume that $b$ is surjective. Is the following a correct construction of the group $D$, given the rest of the diagram?
Let $I = \operatorname{ker}(b) \subseteq A$. Let $J = a(I) \subseteq B$. Let $K \subseteq B$ be the normal closure of $J$. Take $D = B / K$ and take $c$ to be quotient mapping.
Consider any $x \in I$. We have that $a(x) \in a(I) = J \subseteq K$. Hence, $c(a(x)) = e \in D = B / K$. Therefore, $I \subseteq \operatorname{ker}(c \circ a)$. Thus, $c \circ a: A \to D$ factors through $C = A / I$, so we obtain a map $d: C \to D$ with $c \circ a = d \circ b$. Hence the diagram is commutative when this construction is employed.

You had a few typos. The map factors through $A/I$, and the map $d$ originates in $C$, not $B$. Technically, $C$ is only isomorphic to $A/I$, but ok.

@ArturoMagidin Thank you.

To verify the construction is the pushout, we need to check that for all $x\in A$ we have $d(b(x)) = c(a(x))$, and that if $G$ is any group, and $f\colon B\to G$ and $h\colon C\to G$ are morphisms such that $f\circ a=h\circ b$, then there exists a unique morphism $\phi\colon D\to G$ such that $f=\phi\circ c$ and $h=\phi\circ d$. We identify $C$ with $A/I$.
Indeed, if $x\in A$, then $c(a(x)) = a(x)K$. By construction given $xI\in A/I$, we have $d(xI) = a(x)K$. So we do have equality of compositions.
Now assume that $G$, $f,h$ are given as above. If $y\in K$, then $y$ can be expressed as a product of conjugates
$$a(x_1)^{y_1}\cdots a(x_m)^{y_m}$$
with $x_i\in I$ and $y_j\in B$. Therefore,
$$\begin{align*}
f(y) &= f(a(x_1))^{f(y_1)}\cdots f(a(x_m))^{f(y_m)}\\
     &= h(b(x_1))^{f(y_1)}\cdots h(b(x_m))^{f(y_m)}\\
     &= h(eI)^{f(y_1)}\cdots h(eI)^{f(y_m)}\\
     &= e.
\end{align*}$$
Therefore, $f$ must factor through $B/K=D$, and we obtain a map $\phi\colon D\to G$ such that $\phi(zK)=f(z)$ for all $z\in B$.
In particular, $\phi(c(x)) = \phi(xK) = f(x)$, so $\phi\circ c = f$. To check that $\phi\circ d =h$, let $xI\in A/I$. Then $h(xI) = h(b(x)) = f(a(x)) = \phi(c(a(x)) = \phi(d(b(x)) = \phi\circ d(xI)$. So $h=\phi\circ d$, as required.
Finally, to verify uniqueness, this follows because $c$ is surjective (it's the canonical projection). So if $\psi\colon D\to G$ also satisfies that $f=\psi\circ c$ and $h=\psi\circ d$, then $\psi\circ c = f = \phi\circ c$, and surjectivity of $c$ means it can be cancelled on the right, so $\phi=\psi$. Thus, $(D,c,d)$ is indeed the pushout of the diagram.

"If $y\in K$, then we have that $y=a(x)$ for some $x\in I$" I don't think this is quite correct, for this we would need $y \in J$.

@Smiley1000 Fixed.

Actually, I think there might be an easier way to show the part I have just critized: First show that $J \subseteq \operatorname{ker}(f)$ and then use that $\operatorname{ker}(f)$ is normal to deduce that $K \subseteq \operatorname{ker}(f)$.

@Smiley1000 Either works.

@Smiley1000 Please don't substitute your argument for mine in my post.

Thanks a lot for your answer!
